# Accessing Rundeck with temporary credentials

Tags: rundeck

Currently, Rundeck is connecting the nodes through password authentication. We have setup the active directory authentication for the servers with privilege rule, that password resets after the session disconnects(say temporary password). Do we have any plugins for rundeck to handle this?

```
<node name="SERVER1" description="Test" tags="" hostname="10.10.10.1" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="4.4.0-53-generic" authentication="password"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can config your node through [Job Level Authentication](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#ssh-password-with-a-job-option), basically, it's about pass options to your `resources.xml` file, an example of "dynamic" resources file can be:

```xml
<node name="SERVER1" description="Test" tags="" hostname="10.10.10.1" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="4.4.0-53-generic" authentication="password" ssh-password-option="option.youroption" />
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29993686/10426011) you can see another example.